# Change the font size of a specific monitor

Tags: windows-7, multi-monitor

I have a computer running on Microsoft Windows 7 and connected to 2 monitors, which have two different resolutions. I'm looking for a program that can increase the font size of a specific monitor (and not all monitors). It's ok if it enlarges everything in the monitor (and not just the font size.)

Any license and price is fine.

---

Microsoft Windows 7 allows changing the font size on all monitors, but the setting can't be configured for a specific monitor:

[image]

Comment: Would lowering the screen resolution on the monitor you want a larger font on work?

Comment: @anonymous2 sorry I should've mentioned I cannot change the resolution of the monitors

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I'll delete my answer then.